# Create observable array from api response

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

In Angular 2+ (4.3.6) I am using the new HttpClient with a REST api.
The api returns a json object defined as follows:

```
{
   count: number,
   results: MyObject[]
}
```

In my api service I have the following function to retrieve the data:

```
public getList(): Observable<ApiResponse> {
return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(url); }
```

In my app component I would like to display the data of the objects in the array using the 'async' pipe. Therefor I have a variable called results

```
results: Observable<MyObject[]>;
```

and in the init function

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.results = this.myService.getList();
}
```

and finally in the template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of results | async">
          {{ item.id }}
</div>
```

I am quite new to Angular and can not figure it out how to access the results array using the async pipe without creating a local object like:

```
temp: MyObject[];
ngOnInit() {
    this.temp = this.myService.getList().subscribe(data => this.temp = data.results);
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: That's just how it work more or less. `http request` --> `observable` --> `subscription` ---> data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the `map` operator is for - it allows you to create an observable based on a transformation of another:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";    

this.results = this.myService.getList().map(res => res.results);
```

You can then access this via the async pipe or a subscription.

Comment: Curious to see if this is what they were actually looking for. Sounded like they wanted to skip the observable inside the component. They still need to create that as a local object.

Comment: @Z.Bagley: Yeah, the question wasn't 100% clear whether they wanted to skip the class field entirely or just avoid subscribing and extracting the value manually. I assumed the latter, but if it ends up being the former I'll delete/edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the question, so I'll rewrite your possible errors :

1 - You service returns an Observable, meaning you should subscribe to it and set the value into the subscribe :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getList().subscribe(list => this.results = list);
}
```

2 - Since you do that, you should type your results as results (or your customObject)

```
results: MyObject[];
```

3 - Angular responses return a custom object that you need to map before returning :

```
return this.http.get(url).map(r => r.json() ? r.json() : r);
```

After that, in your HTML, the async pipe should work.